# Is there a sort of "two-sided semidirect product"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, products, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Let $G,H$ be groups. Suppose we have both an action of $G$ on $H$, and an action of $H$ on $G$, both non-trivial. Let "$\cdot$" define the former action, and $\circ$ define the latter.

What can we say about the product:
$$
(g,h)\,(g',h') := \big(g\,(h\circ g'), h\,(g\cdot h')\big),
$$

or the product:
$$
(g,h)\,(g',h') := \big(g\,(h\circ g'), (g'\cdot h)\,h'\big),
$$

or anything similar where the other action is a right action?

> Do we have a group?
>   Is this used somewhere?
>   Is it useful, or too general?

Thank you.

Comment: You might compare to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product

Comment: Probably this operation fails to be associative unless you specify a compatibility between the two actions (which should just be the last two axioms in the Wikipedia article Jack Schmidt linked to).